# Detect enter event with two element Id in one jsp

Tags: javascript, jquery

Why does alert shows only on the last event? My goal is to make all enter event works. Thanks.

This is mycode :

```
$(document).off('keyup').on('keyup','#main',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) alert("enter on main input");
    });

    $(document).off('keyup').on('keyup','#other1',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) alert("enter on other input");
    });
```

see this [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/n368drr6/) for demo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're removing the keyup handler straight after adding it.  This is, in effect, what you are doing now...

```
$(document).off('keyup');

$(document).on('keyup','#main',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) alert("enter on main input");
});

$(document).off('keyup');  // this removes the event handler you just created

$(document).on('keyup','#other1',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) alert("enter on other input");
});
```

Split the code so it's clearer what's going on, like this...

```
$(document).off('keyup');

$(document).on('keyup','#main',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) alert("enter on main input");
});

$(document).on('keyup','#other1',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) alert("enter on other input");
});
```

or you can chain the whole thing like this...

```
$(document)
    .off('keyup');
    .on('keyup','#main',function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13) alert("enter on main input");
    });
    .on('keyup','#other1',function(e){
        if(e.keyCode == 13) alert("enter on other input");
    });
```

That has the advantage of only creating the jQuery object for the document once, rather than 3 times as above.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you are using `.off('keyup')` which cancels previous binding of the keyup event, so only the last event handler is bound.

Simply remove the `.off('keyup')`

Answer (score 1):

As stated in the other answers, when you use the off method on the keyup event handler you are removing all of the previous bindings on that event.
Splitting the code seems to be a better choice for this particular question but another way of solving your problem is using namespaces.

```
$(document).off('keyup.main').on('keyup.main','#main',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) alert("enter on main input");
});

$(document).off('keyup.other1').on('keyup.other1','#other1',function(e){
    if(e.keyCode == 13) alert("enter on other input");
});
```